# createObjectURL error: `argument must be an instance of Blob. Received an instance of Blob`

Tags: node.js, express, file, fetch

I have an express route which contains the following:

```
let result = await fetch("http://someurl");
result = await result.blob();
console.log(result)
const img = URL.createObjectURL(result);
```

This produces the following error (on line 4):

`TypeError: The "obj" argument must be an instance of Blob. Received an instance of Blob`

What's going on here?

If it helps, the result of the console.log is:

```
Blob {
  [Symbol(type)]: 'image/png',
  [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer 89 50 4e  ... 481501 more bytes>
}
```

and the fetch route goes to another express app which calls `res.sendFile(myfilepath)`

Comment: Not an answer to the question above, but it seems like createObjectURL is not the way to go on a backend server. I ended up calling `Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer())` to get direct access to the file data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server-side equivalent of:

```
let result = await fetch("http://someurl");
result = await result.blob();
console.log(result)
const img = URL.createObjectURL(result);
```

is

```
let result = await fetch("http://someurl");
result = await result.arrayBuffer();
console.log(result)
const img = Buffer.from(result).toString("base64"));
```

and the image is then rendered client-side with something similar to:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <%= img %>">
```

Using EJS, for this example; the point here being to translate the image data into base-64 encoded text, which can then be rendered using an image data URI (https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Note that this sort of hoop-jumping is only required when getting the image data requires some sort of server-side authentication, as in most cases you'd just do:

```html
<img src="http://someurl">
```

I have the following (cut-down) code where images are accessible only after authenticating:

```js
export function getImage({ imageUrl, token }) {
  return fetch(`${apiServer}/${imageUrl}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then((blob) => Buffer.from(blob).toString("base64"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your comment, this will happen when `URL.createObjectURL` is used on a server, usually by an app using Server-Side Rendering.

You can perform a `document` check to ensure you're in a browser before calling `URL.createObjectURL` like this:

```js
let result, img

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  result = await fetch("http://someurl");
  result = await result.blob();
  console.log(result)
  img = URL.createObjectURL(result);
}
```

Comment: How to do the same in server side?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlcreateobjecturlblob